# cannot get sudo to work on my acct (new install of Fedora 34)

Tags: fedora, sudo

I think it's best explained with copy/paste of the terminal.

```
[myuser@fedora ~]$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for myuser: 
myuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
[myuser@fedora ~]$ grep -i myuser /etc/group
wheel:x:10:myuser
myuser:x:1000:
[myuser@fedora ~]$ su -
Password: 
[root@fedora ~]# grep -i wheel /etc/sudoers
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong and how do I fix this? Thanks

Edit: in fedora installation, I had the option to create a new user. I did that and made the new user a member of wheel. Also I've restarted the PC twice because I had to install additional apps that requires a restart.

Comment: Did you login again after adding your user to `wheel`?

Comment: Edited my original post. Thang

Comment: Output of `id` run as the `myuser` account please

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if your account is listed in group wheel in /etc/group .
It matters if your current login session is a member of group wheel.  Try the `id` command to determine that.

There are several ways to add a group.  The most obvious one is to add your account to the group in /etc/group but this only works for future sessions -- so you would need to start a new login session after adding your account to the group.

The `id` command should show if your current process is in the wheel group or not.  Checking contents of /etc/group is not sufficient to determine if you are in group wheel (yet).

Comment: Edited my original post. Thang

Comment: It is not the login session that matters. It is the process that runs `sudo`. It is (as this answer says) possible to create a new process that is a member of the new group, if you have sufficient privileges (e.g. `sudo` or `su`). But usually easier to re-login. Note if you edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow an existing group/user then it work immediately ( `/etc/sudoers` is read every time `sudo` is run, `etc/groups` usually only read when `login` (or equivalent) or `chgrp` is run.

Comment: `chgrp` changes file permissions, not process group permissions.  The command you are thinking of is `newgrp`